# Vimscript: get all matches of a regex over a string

Tags: regex, vim

In vimscript, we have `substitute` function which will accept flag `'g'` to substitute all occurrences.

Is there a way to get all the matches strings?

For example, with string `'x y z'`, we can use `substitute('x y z', '[a-z]', 'abc', 'g')` to change it into `abc abc abc`.

However, is there any way to get the individual characters `['x', 'y', 'z']`?

I know we can use `match()` to get the matched position, and `matchstr()` to get the matched string. But if I want to iterate through all matches, I have to call both functions which I think is not the efficient way.

So Is there any efficient way for getting all matches of a string in vimscript?

Comment: you can capture the matched string and then access it using back-reference. Something like: `substitute('x y z', '([a-z])', '\1', 'g')` will give `x y z`

Comment: @AnuragPeshne In this way, I will have extra things(space) that are not matched by the pattern. Say I want to  extract `'a', 'b', 'c'` from `'ax bx cy'`. And `substitute('ax bx cy', '([a-c])', '\1', 'g')` will still give me the unmatched characters('x', 'y' and space).

Comment: That is because your substitution expression is same as the captured expression. Doing `substitute('ax bx cy', '\([a-c]\)[x-y]', '\1', 'g')` will consume 'x' and 'y' and give you back 'a b c'

Comment: `substitute('ax bx cy', '\([a-c]\)[x-y] \?', '\1', 'g')` will consume ` ` (space).

Comment: @AnuragPeshne I understand. That means I have to write the pattern I care as well as the pattern for the contents that I don't care(space in this case) to strip it. And I think that is not handy enough.

Comment: I agree, nevertheless I have another idea: `substitute('ax bx cy', '\([a-c]\)[^a-c]', '\1', 'g')` - that is capture the pattern cared about and then negate the same pattern.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a substitute with a sub-replace-expression to capture all the matches.

```
let str = 'a b c'
let lst = []
call substitute(str, '[a-z]', '\=add(lst, submatch(0))', 'g')
```

For more help see:

```
:h sub-replace-expression
:h substitute
:h add()
:h submatch()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can negate the regexp to match what's *not* needed, you can use `split()`; it will remove all matches from the string and return a List of the remainders in bewtween:

```
:echo split('x y z', ' ')
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: With `'\v\ze(x|y|z)'`, all the elements that match are solutions -> `:echo map(filter(split(the_string, '\v\ze'.pat), 'v:val =~ "\\v^".pat'), 'matchstr(v:val, "\\v^".pat)')`

Comment: @LucHermitte This `\ze` hack is quite amazing! However I think Peter's solution is more intuitive.

Comment: Definitively. Every time, I need something where `split()` could help, I spend time looking for "how did I proceed last time?". Most of the time, I found another way, which is much simpler.